# jquery making a column editable with a select

Tags: jquery

hey guys I have a sample running at: http://plnkr.co/edit/B9fJQwgdLXEqBhrIJI76?p=preview

right now if I **click** in edit icon `<i class="fa fa-pencil-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>` just the column **name** and **country** can be editable i would like the column order be editable and able to save too as a dropdown.

I need just save  in the html, so for example if I click in edit the first column changes to dropdown after save back to be text understand? as the others 2 columns ?

what I am trying to do is make the first column  editable as a drop-down like the 2 others one with this select

```
<select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control">
            <option value="1">option 1</option>
            <option value="2">option 2</option>
            <option value="2">option 3</option>
</select>
```

as well i would like save the values too.

css:

```
div.addRow{
      line-height: 45px;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding-left: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
    border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5;}
```

html:

```
<table id="example" class="display" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>order</th>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>country</th>
        <th>action</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>


  <table id="newRow" style="display:none">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control">
            <option value="1">option 1</option>
            <option value="2">option 2</option>
            <option value="2">option 3</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>DVap
        </td>
        <td>
          www</td>
        <td><i class="fa fa-pencil-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-minus-square" aria-hidden="true"></i> </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

jquery:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

      var table;

      $("#example").on("mousedown", "td .fa.fa-minus-square", function(e) {
        table.row($(this).closest("tr")).remove().draw();
      })

      $("#example").on('mousedown.edit', "i.fa.fa-pencil-square", function(e) {

        $(this).removeClass().addClass("fa fa-envelope-o");
        var $row = $(this).closest("tr").off("mousedown");
        var $tds = $row.find("td").not(':first').not(':last');

        $.each($tds, function(i, el) {
          var txt = $(this).text();
          $(this).html("").append("<input type='text' value=\""+txt+"\">");
        });

      });

      $("#example").on('mousedown', "input", function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
      });

      $("#example").on('mousedown.save', "i.fa.fa-envelope-o", function(e) {

        $(this).removeClass().addClass("fa fa-pencil-square");
        var $row = $(this).closest("tr");
        var $tds = $row.find("td").not(':first').not(':last');

        $.each($tds, function(i, el) {
          var txt = $(this).find("input").val()
          $(this).html(txt);
        });
      });


       $("#example").on('mousedown', "#selectbasic", function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
      });


      var url = 'http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/ccTtqmPbkO?indent=2';
      table = $('#example').DataTable({
        ajax: url,
        rowReorder: {
          dataSrc: 'order',
          selector: 'tr'
        },
        columns: [{
          data: 'order'
        }, {
          data: 'place'
        }, {
          data: 'name'
        }, {
          data: 'delete'
        }]
      });

      $('#example').css('border-bottom', 'none');
    $('<div class="addRow"><button id="addRow">Add New Row</button></div>').insertAfter('#example');

      // add row
      $('#addRow').click(function() {
        //t.row.add( [1,2,3] ).draw();
        var rowHtml = $("#newRow").find("tr")[0].outerHTML
        console.log(rowHtml);
        table.row.add($(rowHtml)).draw();
      });
    });
```

Comment: *what I am trying to do is make the first column editable...* **OK**  *...as a drop-down...* **???** *...like the 2 others...* **2 other what?** *...one with this select* **Whhhaaa??**

Comment: hahha sorry i might confuse the things really sorry for this I edit my question, right now if I **click** in edit icon `<i class="fa fa-pencil-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>` just the column **name** and **country** can be editable i would like the column order be editable and able to save too as a dropdown.

Comment: I see, so the first column needs to be editable and then you'd like to save your data. Saved to a server or locally? I'm not sure on how the select plays into this though.

Comment: I need just save  in the html, so for example if I click in edit the first column changes to dropdown after save back to be text understand? as the others 2 columns ?

Comment: The only drop down I see is `show [] entries` When in edit mode the other 2 columns turn into text inputs.